# Proving that $\inf\{ n^{1/n} > 1 : n \in \mathbb{N} \}=1$ using only that $1 + ma \le (1+a)^m$ for every $a>0$ and $m \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to find the infimum of the following:

$S = \{ n^{1/n} > 1 : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$

using the fact that $1 + ma \le (1+a)^m$ where $a>0$, $m \in \mathbb{N}$

**What I tried**:

I know $\xi: \mathbb{N}-\{1,2\} \mapsto \mathbb{R}^+$,  $\xi(n)=n^{1/n}$ is decreasing, and already know $\inf S=1$.

But using the fact above, I would like to show the following.

$$
\forall \epsilon >0, \exists n>2 : (1+\epsilon)^n \ge n
$$

But I can't proceed.

Comment: You know that $$(1+\epsilon)^n\geqslant1+n\epsilon\geqslant n\epsilon$$ hence $$(1+\epsilon)^{2n}=(1+\epsilon)^n\cdot(1+\epsilon)^n\geqslant(n\epsilon)^2=n^2\epsilon^2$$ and the RHS is at least $2n$ for every $$n\geqslant\frac2{\epsilon^2}$$

Comment: It's probably $\inf\{n^{1/n}:n\in\mathbb{N},n>1\}$, otherwise it's trivial.

Comment: @Did I think it's elegant.

Comment: @egreg edited, thx